# z-index problem in IE7

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

Problem in IE 7: When I mouse over the question mark icon, the tooltip javascript popup is not completely shown in IE 7. Bottom portion is hidden behind the "Auto Assign" block. How can I show the entire tooltip popup?

Here is the jsFiddle link : http://jsfiddle.net/FLyXM/1/

Comment: post your relevant code here. not the whole thing just the relevant.

Comment: updated http://jsfiddle.net/FLyXM/2/

Comment: please rephrase your question. give details on what is the problem. and show the css that you think affects it. it's hard to give any answer when you don't know what is the question or the problem

Comment: When I mouse over on question icon, pin pop-up will come. Auto assign block is overlapping that pop-up in IE7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just apply z-index:1 to Pin field li where you place the tooltip. 
Thats it!

Answer (score 0):

`z-index` only works on positioned elements. Give the element `position:relative` or something. Also, please use the enter key more when coding css, your's is very hard to read.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/z-index

Comment: Simplified the code for better understand. here is the link : http://jsfiddle.net/FLyXM/10/